# Using Participle-1 of werden in a compound adjective

Tags: participle, compound-adjective

I am currently summarizing an article on the theme of "Die Arbeitswelt von morgen" and have put together the following sentence:

> Wegen des Aufstiegs der Wissensarbeit dominiert teamorientierte
>   Projektarbeit über *unwichtigwerdende* Hierarchien.

Is the compound adjective "*unwichtigwerdend*" used correctly in this context?

Comment: "Wissensarbeit" sounds like a neologism to me, might need further definition. A modern myth telling that Germans combine things to very long words notwithstanding, i'd write "unwichtig werdend" as two words. Apart from that it sounds ok to me ...

Comment: @Nico - Indeed,  a relative clause would work just fine. I wanted to practise using the participle in this case! :)  By the way, could you tell me what "red type" means?

Comment: "Unwichtigwerdende" als Kompositum habe ich noch nicht gesehen und sehe auch kein Problem darin, das auseinander zu schreiben; im Gegenteil. A_dondas Kommentare werte ich nicht hoch, weil "Wissensarbeit" mir unproblematisch erscheint. Lt. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Wissensarbeit%2CKopfarbeit&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWissensarbeit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CKopfarbeit%3B%2Cc0 ngram hat Wissensarbeit um 2000 die Kopfarbeit in Büchern überflügelt, begegnet ist es mir aber zugegebenermaßen selten.

Comment: Kopfarbeit setzt auch einen leicht anderen Schwerpunkt. Viel zu wissen ist ohne viel zu denken möglich und umgekehrt. Inhaltlich bewerten möchte ich den Satz hier nicht. :) Oh, in meinem letzten Kommentar hätte es natürlich heißen müssen "a_dondas Kommentar", Einzahl.

Comment: And I thought those from the future were already included :-)

Comment: @SatishVasan Why don't you use a relative clause such as "Hierarchien, die zunehmend unwichtig werden"? Your formulation sounds very "red tape-like" ("red type" was a typo...).

Comment: @Red tape issues" are bureaucratic ones and sometimes also denote the lingustic style used for them

Comment: "Wegen des Aufstiegs der Wissensarbeit dominiert teamorientierte Projektarbeit über *zunehmend irrelevante* Hierarchien."

Comment: Die Antworten legen nahe, dass Dein Satz so verstanden wird, als dominiere Teamarbeit über Arbeit in Hierarchien. So, wie er da steht, besagt er aber, dass die Teamarbeit über die Hierarchien selbst dominiert. Es ist unwahrscheinlich, dass das gesagt werden soll, aber möglich. Inhaltlich zweifelhaft ist, dass es überhaupt einen Gegensatz von Team und Hierarchie gibt: Natürlich gibt es in Teams Hierarchien und natürlichen lassen sich Teams prächtig in Hierarchien integrieren.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...dominiert teamorientierte Projektarbeit über **unwichtiger** werdende
>   Hierarchien.

By separating the words and using the comparative it seems better to me. "Unwichtig" is a normal adjective here, not a prefix to "werden". And "become unimportant" is rather "become less and less important" here.

---

But there is a kind of mismatch in the comparison:

> - teamorientierte Projektarbeit
> - unwichtigwerdende Hierarchi**en**

The singular/plural does not match. "teamorientiert" is defining, while "unwichtig werdende" is declaring (and questionable). It is logically not clear what the cause and effect is.

I would formulate:

> Wegen des Aufstiegs der Wissensarbeit dominier**en teamorientierte
>   Projekte mehr und mehr über hierarchische Ansätze.**

Now, "Ansatz" is nothing interesting, but just like *Wissensarbeit* it should be possible to find something from the context. "Hierarchien" alone is not enough, no matter which language.

I also eliminated the doubling of *-arbeit* in *Wissensarbeit* and *Projektarbeit*.

The "mehr und mehr" picks up the movement of "Aufstieg" and in the end replaces the original "unwichtigwerdende".

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a bit klunky.

I would phrase it this way

> Wegen des Aufstiegs der Wissensarbeit, dominiert teamorientierte Projektarbeit immer stärker über althergebrachte Hierarchien.

Comment: Das Komma ist zwar nachvollziehbar, aber ich glaube es ist falsch; es ist ja nur ein "wegen", keine Konjunktion. "Wegen des Wetters sind wir umgekehrt" etc.